# How can Inject a Spring bean into an implementation of DynamoDBMarshaller<T>?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

This is a contrived example, but it illustrates my question.  I want to create a custom `DynamoDBMarshaller<T>` to marshall/unmarshall my objects to/from the database.  It requires the `CustomMarshaller` Spring bean, which needs to be injected into the MyAttributeMarshaller class after it's instantiated.  However, since this class is created through the @DynamoDBMarshalling() annotation, it's not managed by Spring.  Is there a way to make my CustomMarshaller spring bean available in the MyAttributeMarshaller class?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "MyTable")
public class ObjectInTable 
{
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "myAttribute")
  @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = MyAttributeMarshaller.class)
  public MyAttribute getMyAttribute() { ... }
  public MyAttribute setMyAttribute(MyAttribute o) { ... }
}
```

And my marsher class..

```
@Named
public class MyAttributeMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<MyAttribute>
{
    @Override
    public String marshall(MyAttribute o)
    {
        return marshaller.marshall(o);
    }
    @Override
    public ProviderContentReference unmarshall(Class<ProviderContentReference> clazz, String obj)
    {
        return marshaller.unmarshall(o);
    }
    @Inject
    private CustomMarshaller marshaller; // ERROR: null
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

I found a solution that seems to work by first creating a Spring bean:

```
@Named
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

And then retrieving my Custom Marshaller in the Non-Spring managed `MyAttributeMarshaller` by:

```
private CustomMarshaller marshaller = (CustomMarshaller)
    SpringContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("customMarshaller");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid not. You are asking DynamoDB to use an specific instance of that marshaller class which has been injected by Spring with a CustomMarshaller.

You could put a CustomMarshaller instance in an static place/field and pick it up from MyAttributeMarshaller but this is a shot in the dark since the posted code is not enough to say for sure